# How to reject arrays with unwanted number range

Tags: arrays, ruby

I need to create a method which should receive as argument only an array of numbers between 1 and 6. If the argument is something different I want to exit the method with an error message.

What method score(dice) does is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749973/ruby-greed-koan-how-can-i-improve-my-if-then-soup)

I thought of using a double conditional clause such as:

```
if (dice.is_a? Array ) && ("elements of dice are numbers of range (1..6)")
do something
else print "error message"
```

In place of the string "element of dice are numbers of range (1..6)" I tried the following code but does not work:

```
dice.each { |num| num <= 6 }
```

What would you suggest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable#all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F)

```
dice.all? {|num| (1..6).include? num}
```

Comment: will 1..6 be created every time? If so, maybe use something to store it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def score *dice
  raise "this is not an array" unless dice.is_a? Array 
  raise "atleast one value is required in array" unless dice.length > 0
  raise "array should only contain numbers between 1 to 6" unless dice.all? { |i| (1..6).include?(i) }
  #your code here#
 end
```